# Get output of shell command in Rust as a string

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a simple CLI in Rust.

```
let output = Command::new("which")
        .arg("brew")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");
```

I would like to get `output` in the form of a string for comparison. How do I do that?

Comment: The `Output` struct has a [`stdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Output.html#structfield.stdout) member which you can use together with the dup question.

Comment: "use together with the dup question" implies that this question is not a duplicate. Someone's standards are way too high for what is/isn't considered a duplicate.